# Python cumsum increment every time new value is encountered

Tags: python, r

Coming from R, the code would be

```
x       <- data.frame(vals = c(100,100,100,100,100,100,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,300,300,300,300,300))
x$state <- cumsum(c(1, diff(x$vals) != 0))
```

Which marks every time the difference between rows is non-zero, so that I can use it to spot transitions in data, like so:

```
   vals state
1   100     1
...
7   200     2
...
14  300     3
```

What would be a clean equivalent in Python?

**Additional question**

The answer to the original question is posted below, but won't work properly for a grouped dataframe with pandas.

Data here: https://pastebin.com/gEmPHAb7. Notice that there are 2 different filenames.

When imported as `df_all` I group it with the following, and then apply solution posted below.

```
df_grouped = df_all.groupby("filename")
df_all["state"] = (df_grouped['Fit'].diff() != 0).cumsum()
```

Comment: Maybe just mimic it? `import pandas as pd;import numpy as np;x = pd.DataFrame({'vals': [100,100,100,100,100,100,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,300,300,300,300,300]});x['state'] = np.cumsum(np.insert(np.diff(x.vals) != 0, 0, 1));x`. I dunno if that's a "clean" python equivalent, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `diff` and `cumsum`, as in your `R` example:

```
df['state'] = (df['vals'].diff()!= 0).cumsum()
```

This uses the fact that `True` has integer value 1

## Bonus question

```
df_grouped = df_all.groupby("filename")
df_all["state"] = (df_grouped['Fit'].diff() != 0).cumsum()
```

I think you misunderstand what `groupby` does. All groupby does is create groups based on the criterium (`filename` in this instance). You then need to tell add another operation to tell what needs to happen with this group.
Common operations are `mean`, `sum`, or more advanced as `apply` and `transform`. 
You can find more information [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jakevdp/PythonDataScienceHandbook/blob/master/notebooks/03.08-Aggregation-and-Grouping.ipynb) or [here](http://pbpython.com/pandas_transform.html)

If you can explain more in detail what you want to achieve with the groupby I can help you find the correct method. If you want to perform the above operation per filename, you probably need something like this:

```
def get_state(group):
    return (group.diff()!= 0).cumsum()

df_all['state'] = df_all.groupby('filename')['Fit'].transform(get_state)
```

Comment: Thanks. Bonus question: is there any reason why this shouldn't worked on a grouped pandas df, or am I having a syntax error?

Comment: I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work on a grouped DataFrame. I don't see any code, so I cannot judge on the syntax error

Comment: First I make a group, `df_grouped = df_all.groupby("filename")` and then I apply the above solution, in a new column `df_all["state"] = (df_grouped['Fit'].diff() != 0).cumsum()`

However, it appears as if `cumsum` ignored the grouping entirely.

Comment: Edited now. See original.